# How to receive GET request from URL

Tags: php, esi

I am used to **SEND** all sorts of requests to 'foreign' URLs or to my web site Server URL and receive responses and such.

And thus, I am used to receive requests as well.

*BUT*

Only if it targets a **PHP** file like so : `http://www.example.com/file.php`

In order for a core part of my future web site feature to work, I need to be able to listen to a GET request made to a "blank" URL like so : `http://www.example.com/blank/?key1=value1&key2=value2`

Is there a way to 'run' a PHP script whenever this URL is called? Even if it is not targeted directly in the request? Any other script?

I'm ignorant when it comes to server-side mechanisms.

EDIT :

I have tried to create a file.PHP with the following :

```
$key1 = $_GET['key1'];
$key2 = $_GET['key2'];
echo "$key1 and $key2";
```

but response is 403 (forbidden)

---

EDIT2 : To my moderator : the question linked is not the exact same question as mine. He asks to hide the **file** extension, I ask how to target a **directory**. Even if the answer has the same source (htaccess) it is not the same thought process.
Further more, my title explicitly mentions **requests** (hence the tags API and ESI) and not only the PHP subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: Yes but how to do it exactly depends on your web server software. For Apache for example, you can [use a `.htaccess` file](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/) to create rewrite rules to make paths matching a certain pattern (e.g. `/blank/<whatever>`) behave as if they were another path (e.g. `/blank.php`).

But in your case where you actually have `/blank/` as "directory", there is an even simpler way: **Put an `index.php` file into the directory.**

It's an almost universal convention that if a *directory* is specified in the URL (without specific filename), the server will look for an `index.php` file (or `index.html`, but your question was about PHP in particular) in the directory and direct the request there.

Comment: It works perfectly ! (with echo)
I am so glad i was going down this path with htaccess, a couple more days and i would've found the solution. ahah :D
Thank you so much for saving those for me <3